# @RequestBody contains only null values with kotlin data class in integration test scope

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, kotlin

@Edit

Issue is not related to validation.
After investigation I found out that when executing my code using any Rest client (ie RestTemplate/WebTestClient) in integration test with @SpringBootTest the @RequestBody after parsing always has null values. It works fine in normal env.

```
@PostMapping("/url")
fun executeFun(
    @Valid @RequestBody MyDataClass: MyData
) = ...

data class MyDataClass(
@field:Size(min = 3, max = 5
) val myValidatedField: String = "")
```

)

Example of my data class and I can see that web test client produced desired request:

```
 POST http://localhost:62211/url
 WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
 Content-Type: [application/json]
 Content-Length: [49]

{"myvalidatedField":"1234"}
```

My integration class looks something like this

````
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
internal class { 
....

@Test
    fun web_Client_2() {
       val myData = MyDataClass("1234")
        webClient.post().uri(URI_WITH_CONTEXT_PATH)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(myData)
            .exchange()
    }```
````

Comment: could you please add the WebTestClient call and maybe the error that is given?

Comment: Where is the assertion?

Comment: Does assertion matters? I just posted what I 'could' since when debugging i can see that input in controller Is data instance with empty fields